# Write multiple quantifier statement as psuedocode

Tags: computer-science, quantifiers, programming

I want to write an algorithm for determining the truth value of:
"for all $x \in D$, $\exists y \in E$ such that $x$ and $y$ satisfy $P(x,y)$"

and

"$\exists x \in D$ such that $\forall y \in E$, $x$ and $y$ satisfy $P(x,y)$"

in pseudo-code, for generic D, E, P(x,y), for the benefit of computer science students' understanding.

Comment: "pseudocode" ???

Comment: pseu·do·code
/ˈso͞odōˌkōd/

noun: pseudo-code
a notation resembling a simplified programming language, used in program design.

Comment: But there is only one "universal" [syntactical specification for pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode#Syntax) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Read the question again. For the first statement: You choose an x in D, loop over y in E until one satisfies P(x,y); go to the next x, loop over y in E until one satisfies P(x,y), etc. If for some x, no y satisfies P(x,y), the program fails. The inner loop ends each time a y is found which satisfies P(x,y) for that chosen x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need an interpretation of the predicates $D$, $E$ and $P$ in some structure $\mathcal{M}$.

My answer assumes that :

- $\mathcal{M}$ is finite, and its support represented by an (informatic) enumerable $M$
- The predicates $D,E,P$ are represented by boolean-valued functions.

The function satisfies_formula1 bellow will return True if the formula $\forall x \in D, \ \exists y \in E, \ P(x,y)$ holds, false otherwise. The function satisfies_formula2 does the same for the formula $\exists x \in D, \ \forall y \in E, \ P(x,y)$.

```
def satisfies_formula1():
    for x in M:
        if D(x):
            found_y = False  #this answers "did we find y in E such that P(x,y) holds?"
            for y in M:
                if E(y) and P(x,y):
                    found_y = True
            if not found_y:
                return False
    return True

def satisfies_formula2():
    for x in M: 
        if D(x):
            all_y_ok = True  #innocent untill proven guilty
            for y in M:
                if E(y) and not P(x,y):
                    all_y_ok = False
            if all_y_ok:
                return True
```

Comment: OK it is python and not pseudocode but this is even easier to read, no?

Comment: Possible to make this "more presentable" (at the expense of efficiency) with a nested for loop?

Comment: @Nights What do you have in mind? Writing with -any- and -all- ?